# How to access to an object inside a C function

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I need to get access to an object inside a C function similar to this few code

```
@interface MixerHostAudio ()  <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (readwrite) int *alternativeOutput;
@end

@implementation MyCode
@synthesize alternative

void audioInputAvailable () {
   alternative=1;
}
```

I get this error: " 'Use of undeclared identifier 'alternative' "

Any ideas about how can i solve it ?

Comment: If you want to `@synthesize` a `@property` as something other than its exact name, you have to use the format: `@synthesize propertyName = synthesizedName;`.  But chances are pretty good that you should be accessing them via `self.` anyway.

Comment: Remember that every instance variable has a meaning only if it's associated with an object. Instead inside a function, since it's not a method, you can't access to self, you aren't "inside an object".

Answer (score 4):

You have to make your "`MyCode`" object available somewhere for your C glue function to pick up.  For example, if you have a pointer to your MyCode object...

```
void audioInputAvailable(MyCode *myCodeObject){
   myCodeObject.alternative = 1;
}
```